# How to run Node.js proxy encryption service on Android?

Tags: android, node.js, networking

I am using Dory (Node.js runtime on Android), and try to use a proxy encryption service on my phone. The encryption service listen on 1080, and turn regular network request into encrypted package and send to my server, kinda like a VPN but not really. The challenge is, while the node proxy encryption service runs fine on other platforms, it doesn’t seem to work on Android. I change my proxy to 127.0.0.1:1080 in my wifi setting. The log (STDOUT) on Dory shows zero runtime error, and it shows it does receive network request packages (and shows no error encrypting them), but all the network requests when timeout. I also cannot see any network request going out from my phone. Does Dory have no network access?